# How do I replace only the first occurrence of a matched search string in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I have this script but I would like to change so it only replaces the first occurrence of a matched search string:

```html
on findAndReplaceInText(theText, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
 set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSearchString
 set theTextItems to every text item of theText
 set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theReplacementString
 set theText to theTextItems as string
 set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
 return theText
end findAndReplaceInText

findAndReplaceInText("susan", "s", "t") -- returns "tutan" but I want "tusan"
```

I've been searching everywhere but had no success. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any error handling:

```
to findAndReplaceFirstOccurrenceInText(theText, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSearchString
    return text item 1 of theText & theReplacementString & text (text item 2) thru (text item -1) of theText
end findAndReplaceFirstOccurrenceInText
```

Comment: This works and is shorter. But there is still an issue when I want to replace the LAST characters of a string:  findAndReplaceFirstOccurrenceInText("susan", "an", "1") -- returns "sus1n"

Comment: My oversight, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I'be updated vadians code to fix an error when replacing the last character. But I still wish there would be a simpler/shorter solution:

```
on findAndReplaceFirstOccurrenceInText(theText, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
set theOffset to offset of theSearchString in theText
if theOffset is 0 then
    return theText
else if theOffset is 1 then
    tell theText to return theReplacementString & text (theOffset + (length of theSearchString)) thru -1
else if theOffset is length of theText then
    tell theText to return text 1 thru (theOffset - 1) & theReplacementString
else
    tell theText to return text 1 thru (theOffset - 1) & theReplacementString & text (theOffset + (length of theSearchString)) thru -1
end if
```

end findAndReplaceFirstOccurrenceInText